# Reversing a melting operation with reshape2

Tags: r, reshape2

Consider the following code.

```
library (reshape2)
x = rnorm (20)
y = x + rnorm (rnorm (20, sd = .01))

dfr <- data.frame (x, y)
mlt <- melt (dfr)
```

When I try to reverse this operation with dcast,

```
dcast (mlt, value ~ variable)
```

I get instead a data frame with three columns (not suitable for scatter-plotting, for instance).
How can I reenact the original data frame with dcast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How could R know the ordering that existed before the melt? i.e. the notion that row one of `x` matches up with row one of `y`.

If you add an index column (since R will complain about duplicated row.names) you can do this operation simply:

```
dfr$idx <- seq_along(dfr$x)   
mlt <- melt(dfr, id.var='idx')
dcast(mlt, idx ~ variable, value.var='value')
```